# HorizontalScrollView - calculate stop position after fling

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, onfling

With HorizontalScrollView, how do I detect when the scrolling stops after user has flinged the view ? Or alternatively, how do I know at what position the scroll will be when it stops (then I could use it with onScrollChanged).

I have inherited HorizontalScrollView. What I'd like is to have the view behave naturally when user interacts with it but when it stops to update some of its children views - if I do it while the view is scrolling it causes small lags during scroll.

Thanks

Comment: Same requirement, i've tried almost everything let me know if u found something.

Comment: i've found solution for this and will upload here so anyone else need it.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a custom class for `HorizontalScrollView` which has an interface with scroll stop method, which gives the `scrollX` position when scrolling stopped.
here's the code:

```
public class CustomMCSDHorizontalScroll extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private Runnable scrollerTask;
    private int initialPosition;
    private int newCheck = 100;


    public interface onScrollStopedListner{
        void onScrollStoped();
    }

    private onScrollStopedListner onScrollStoped;

    public CustomMCSDHorizontalScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        scrollerTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int newPosition = getScrollX();

                    if ( initialPosition - newPosition == 0 ) {
                        if ( onScrollStoped != null ) {
                            onScrollStoped.onScrollStoped();
                        }
                    } else {
                        initialPosition = getScrollX();
                        CustomMCSDHorizontalScroll.this.postDelayed(
                            scrollerTask, newCheck);
                    }

                }
        };
    }

    public void setOnScrollStopListner (CustomMCSDHorizontalScroll.
            onScrollStopedListner listener) {
        onScrollStoped = listener;
    }

    public void startScrollerTask(){
        initialPosition = getScrollX();
        CustomMCSDHorizontalScroll.this.postDelayed(scrollerTask, newCheck);
    }

}
```

Here's the `ontouch()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.mHorizontalScrollViewMain:
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                hsvUpperTab.startScrollerTask();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.mHorizontalScrollViewSub:
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                hsvLowerTab.startScrollerTask();
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's the `onScrollStop()` method:

```
hsvLowerTab.setOnScrollStopListner(new onScrollStopedListner() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStoped() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getLowerTabScrolled(hsvLowerTab.getScrollX());
    }
});

hsvUpperTab.setOnScrollStopListner(new onScrollStopedListner() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStoped() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getUpperTabScrolled(hsvUpperTab.getScrollX());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) for the same.

Steps for using a scroller.

1. Subclass HorizontalScrollView to have  a custom view and override the methods onTouchEvent,onInterceptTouchEvent to return false.
2. Implement OnGestureListener in the activity.
3. Pass the onFling motion event to the scroller method

   fling(int startX, int startY, int velocityX, int velocityY, int minX, int maxX, int minY, int maxY)
4. Following scroller methods can be used:

getFinalX() 
getFinalY()

OR

Scan this isFinished() value constantly to  find if the fling is over.

Comment: Apart from this you need to give the MotionEvent to the Horizontal scroll view as well.

Comment: @khotmanish..do you have sample code for this? i am finding it difficult to use it...